# Spring: Check if a classpath resource exists before loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a code where I need to check if a classpath resource exists and apply some actions.

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:my-file.json");
if (file.exists()) {
    // do one thing
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

**Problem:** `ResourceUtils.getFile()` throws `FileNotFoundException` if the resource doesn't exist. At the same time I don't want to use exceptions for code flow and I'd like to check if a resource exists.

**Question:** Is there any way to check if a resource exists using Spring's API?

**Why I need this to be done with Spring:** Because without spring I'd need to pick a correct class loader myself which is not convenient. I'd need to have a different code to make it work in unit tests.

Comment: "At the same time I don't want to use exceptions for code flow". This is what exceptions are made for. Don't make things more complicated than needed by taking on weird self-imposed requirements.

Comment: You can use directly the ResourceLoader interface in your class (by autowiring ) or just foloow my bleow answer in order to use this class in all project !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [ResourceLoader Interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) in order to load use [getResource()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-), then use [Resource.exists()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html#exists--) to check if the file exists or not.

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;  

Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:my-file.json");
if (resource.exists()) {
  // do one thing
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. `resource.exists()` returns false. But it exists for sure.

Comment: Actually, it works. Forgot to add prefix ""classpath:". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's been answered and old but thought of putting is someone sees docker and maven cannot use the same solution even the resource.exists() returns true.  in that case we can do something like this (it's bit hacky though):

```
            Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:path/to/file");
            if (resource.exists()) {
                try {
                    // below throws file not found if the app runs in docker
                    resource.getFile()
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // docker uses this
                    InputStream stream = new ClassPathResource("classpath:path/to/file").getInputStream();                        
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call ***org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils*** without @Autowired.

```
org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ResourceUtils.getFile("yourPath").exists(), "Path is not valid");
```

PS: Utility methods for resolving resource locations to files in the file system. Mainly for internal use within the framework. [documentation link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html).